# Can't move or copy a subsite using content and structure

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to move a subsite under another subsite. I go through the steps to move or copy the site, and nothing happens--no progress indicator, no error message, no activity whatsoever. What could be causing this? Any thoughts?

Comment: which browser you are using? have you tried to clear the browser cache or try different browser

Comment: I was using MS Edge. I tried clearing the cache to no avail, but using Internet Explorer made the difference! Thanks. It never would have occurred to me that Microsoft's browser was the problem.

Comment: Which IE worked? 11 ? You can also try to enable compatibility mode in edge

Comment: I added that's as answer if you marked for both community and my benifits

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is browser issue.i would recommend to try follow:

- try with different browser I.e chrome, ie
- clear the browser cache
- lastly if using edge browser then Try to enable enterprise mode aka compatibility mode